# How to create proper UPDATE query using NOW()?

Tags: zend-framework, zend-db

What's the way of building "UPDATE table SET date = NOW() WHERE id = 1" query ?

```
$table->update(array('date' => 'NOW()'), 'id = 1');
```

Above code doesn't work properly.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
$table->update(array('date' => new Zend_Db_Expr('NOW()'), 'id = 1');
```

See:

http://framework.zend.com/apidoc/core/Zend_Db/Expr/Zend_Db_Expr.html

Answer (score 0):

Did you try using PHP's date function:

```
$table->update(array('date' => date('Y-m-d H:i:s')), 'id = 1');
```